# yes/no :Is $f(x) $ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Is $f(x) = (x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4) +1 $ is  irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

My attempt: yes, by using Eisenstein criterion, $f(x)$ is not reducible.

Is this correct?

Comment: It is quite unclear what prime you are applying Eisenstein to, since $f(0)=5^2$.

Comment: @Gae.S.i mean $ x^{p-1} + ......+1  $ here $p =5$

Comment: You may want to confront your notes on Eisenstein criterion (not Einstein) with some other source (say wikipedia).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: It is $$(5-5x+x^2)^2=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)+1$$